# SQL Server database backup and saving at the same time

Tags: sql-server, backup

What will happen when is running differential backup on SQL Server 2012 and some application is trying save data to table at the same time?

Comment: Yes, sql server will backup the portion of the transaction log required for recovery even if in SIMPLE mode.  At this point when you restore it will have all the most recent data as the transaction log will hold it; and data must be hardened to the log first before updating in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server allow for a database backup while the database is still being used. During a backup, most operations are possible;

for example

```
 INSERT
 UPDATE
 DELETE
```

statements are allowed during a backup operation.

Note : if you try to start a backup operation while a database file is being created or deleted, the backup operation waits until the create or delete operation is finished or the backup times out.

> Importent Note :some Operations that cannot run during a database
>   backup or transaction log backup include the following:

1) File-management operations such as the ALTER DATABASE statement with either the ADD FILE or REMOVE FILE options.

2)Shrink database or shrink file operations. This includes auto-shrink operations.

3)If you try to create or delete a database file while a backup operation is in progress, the create or delete operation fails.

3)If a backup operation overlaps with a file-management operation or shrink operation, a conflict occurs. Regardless of which of the conflicting operation began first, the second operation waits for the lock set by the first operation to time out. (The time-out period is controlled by a session time-out setting.) If the lock is released during the time-out period, the second operation continues. If the lock times out, the second operation fails.

**Reference :msdn**

You can refer this [link](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/debunking-a-couple-of-myths-around-full-database-backups/) it explain the scenario with nice examples

Answer (score 0):

DBMS will take care of these race conditions.It will be done by some  schedule. What called scheduling? you can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schedule_(computer_science)) .